# register with another table relaiton in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 6. I'm trying to add one table relation into user registration.

base code is made by this gentleman

https://github.com/bayu190198/CRUD-RELATION-TABLE-LARAVEL/tree/master/uts_product

I've been got an Undefined variable: branches error at blade file.
Could you teach me what is problem?

Controller

```
protected function create()
{
    $branches = Branch::All();

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'branches' => $branches,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    return view('product.create')->with([
   "data" => $data,
   "branches" => $branches,
]);
```

index.blade.php

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">branch</label>
    <select name="br_id" id="" class="form-control">
      @foreach($branches as $branch)
      <option value="<?=$branch->id?>"><?=$branch->name?></option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
```

Login Controller

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

Branch table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn0fK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I see a problem in that you have two return functions, so when a user is created that Model is returned, the function should then exit.

The second issue is that we can't see the function (index() I presume?) that renders the view. If you're getting the blade directly in the route perhaps move that route to a controller...

So in short the function which is building the index.blade file has no variable `$branches`

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.  Oh I see. yes there are two return. sorry about that.  but I still not sure how to write. Could you show me the correct code pleaes?  One thing original return view was nothing just User::create([ ...]) that's it.

Comment: I need to know which route / function is returning the blade 'index.blade.php'

Comment: I looked web,php but there is no RegisterController function . there is  Auth::routes(); .

Comment: Ok so you've got auth routes only, this means once you login you're redirected somewhere... Do you have a login controller?

Comment: Yes I have LoginController Could you take a look that I update my quesiton.

Comment: The other missing link here is return view('product.create'). I'm not sure you're function is even being run at all, this means you're in some other controller. Try dumping in your controller to see if that function's actually triggered dd(''This is the correct controller')

Comment: I see... I mod little bit andit's hard to explain so I update my question again. I use this person's code. sorry I should've tell you first.

Comment: ok we've got good context now. app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php is where users are created. Which then redirects to 'protected $redirectTo = '/home';'
Now /home is defined in routes 'Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');' So you need to add data to the view from this controller, not in register controller. This controller only pushes you onto the next request (what to do once you're registered)

Comment: Thank you I'm getting understand now but I'm still not sure how to change. Could you show me the code pleaes?

Comment: Firstly tell me which route you're hitting as in the URL eg localhost/home

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register then I would like to go http://127.0.0.1:8000/product  Am I ansering correctrly ? I change only inside of RegisterContoroller. I'm fine with same as original base project code.

Comment: Ok so change this protected $redirectTo = '/home'; to protected $redirectTo = '/product';
then get the product items in the 'ProductController@index' function. I still don't think it will work because $branches = Branch::All(); is a collection and i can't see how you can assign a collection to a database element as seen here 'branches' => $branches,

Comment: I changed protected part. and I update branch tables stracture. Could you take a look please?